# ASP.Net Core website blocks every day at the same time

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2016, kestrel-http-server

I really don't know what to add that't not in the title. I'm running a 2.2 core app on IIS on a Windows Server 2016 server and every day arround 8pm the website blocks and I have to restart it. Nothing in the event viewer, I don't have any schedueled tasks and I don't know where else to look for what might be going wrong.

Comment: "every day arround 8pm the website blocks", what's the meaning of "blocks"?

Comment: All API calls are non-responsive, both API calls that make a DB request and that make some sort of calculation. I have to stop the site in IIS Manager and start it again and all the users need to log out and log in for them to get propper access again.

Comment: You need hang dumps of w3wp.exe or the actual .NET Core processes when the issue happens, and then analysis can reveal the cause.